# React Native not installing properly

Tags: react-native

I am familiar with React Native. I got a new macbook and I am trying to create a new file. However, when I run create-react-native-app [name of app] I am greeted with:

This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]?

When I pressed Y it created the file, however, in a complete file layout. It looked so odd and there were some files missing too.

Normally, when I run create-react-native-app it created the file without asking anything about expo. I am pretty confused. I'm pretty sure I have done wrong somewhere. Where and how I can get the traditional installation process back?

I also know that expo helps with testing. Since may I have been using npm start and npm run ios to test my apps on device and xcode simulation.

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started I followed this.

Comment: did you rmbr to install yarn, brew and watchman?

Comment: Yes, I have react installed on my computer and that builds files properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New version out now and create react native app has been merged with expo CLI.
To avoid any bug use new version to create react apps, follow the command bellow which is also in the link given in your question.

```
  expo init AwesomeProject
```

After installation you will be guided to start project with expo start.

```
  cd AwesomeProject
  expo start
```